# Mouse does not change to pointer on button hover CSS

Tags: css, javafx

I am trying to set the mouse to a pointer when a hover event is detected but the cursor does not change. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would be so grateful.

```
    package replit;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;

    public class Main extends Application 
    { 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(20);

    button button = new Button("Click");
    button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    vbox.getChildren().add(button);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 200);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("Style.css");

    primaryStage.setTitle("A Simple Scene!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
 }
```

The CSS

```
    .button:hover{
    -fx-cursor: pointer;
     }
```

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: .. or in other words: please read the specification (vs. inventing allowed values). Also, put some effort into posting a question, make sure: a)any example you provide at least compiles - this doesn't due to a typo b) the stylesheet is loaded - this doesn't due to an incorrect resource lookup (see at least the java doc, better work through a tutorial), you should see a warning when running